# How can i convert HTML to DOCX with jsoup and docx4j libraries?

Tags: jsoup, docx4j

I want to convert html with table to docx using jsoup and docx4j libraries without ImportXHTML. I need to parse the html file line by line and convert to word. My code is working but not creating table. Thanks in advance.

```
public class TestLinkDocumentGenerator extends Application {
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        WordprocessingMLPackage wordPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();
        MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart = wordPackage.getMainDocumentPart();

        File inputHtmlFile = new File("table.html");
        Document document = Jsoup.parse(inputHtmlFile);
        Elements requirements = document.select("body > table > tbody > tr");
       
        int childCount = 1;
        for(int i=0;i<requirements.size();i++){
            Elements el = requirements.get(i).select("tr:nth-child("+childCount+++") > td");
            for(int j=0;j<el.size();j++){
        mainDocumentPart.addStyledParagraphOfText(el.get(j).cssSelector(), el.get(j).text());
                el.get(j);
                System.out.println("Element : " + el.get(j));

            }
        }
        requirements.select("tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1)");
 
        File exportFile = new File("DEST");
        String DEST = "C:/Users/zhrka/Desktop/testlink_document_generator-Kopya/Sample12.docx";
        wordPackage.save(new java.io.File(DEST));

        Platform.exit();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {Application.launch(args);}
}
```

Comment: Out of curiousity, may I ask why you wish to avoid docx4j-ImportXHTML and re-invent the wheel?  In any case you can study it to understand how to create tables.

Comment: It's necessary task but I'm new and there aren't many examples. If you have examples can you share it? I know i still have to study these libraries. Thanks for looking.